# Angular 2/4 console.log array empty, gettting data from service is async, so it is not going to have data available

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, asynchronous, observable

I have an angular 4 application in which `service` file which is `subscribed` to

Component file I need to have Typescript data fields to set from this data from the subscribed method call.

**PROBLEM -  if console.log is empty ... then seems I need to wait somehow on the data,  but how do I do this,   example somewhere?**

**Data Array**

```
sessionTrackers: ISessionTracker[] = [];
```

**method that subscribes to service call to web api**

```
this.trackerService.getSessionTracker()
    .subscribe(sessionTrackers => {
        this.sessionTrackers = sessionTrackers;
        this.filteredSessions = this.sessionTrackers;
        console.log('real data in subscribe', this.sessionTrackers);
    },
    error => console.log('error : ' + <any>error)

    );
```

Notice that I have `sessionTrackers`  which **INSIDE** the method it works

However when **OUTSIDE** the method it is empty.
Thus its a race condition in which this asynch. operation is not ready

**This outside of method showing empty array**

```
console.log('real data', this.sessionTrackers);
```

I assume it will probably "work" in html ,  but I have fields in typescript I need to set for a reactive form

```
id: number
```

**How can I achieve the data persistence before setting these fields?**

Comment: You can use the resolve property of a route to load the data before displaying the view (your form in this case). The resolve property takes a function that returns a promise. If the promise success, the route is introduced, if rejected, the route stops loading.

Comment: Can you explain more?  An answer or at least some link article?   thx

Comment: I recommend reviewing the Router Documentation, here is a link to the `resolve` featurn https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve. I glanced at this article and it looks like it may help: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: set the form values inside the subscribe this is not a race condition its how async works